# Count total lines with open in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want's in output it show count of all Line numbers in my File, but it show current line number .

```
def __init__(self,file):
    self.count = 0
    self.line_count = 0

def start(self):
    with open(self.usersfile, 'rt') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            if not self.is_alive:break  # when the user presses Ctrl + C, self.is_alive will become False
            username = line.strip().replace('\n', '')
            self.line_count += 1
            self.check_account(username)


def check_account(self,username):
print('{}[+]Trying ({}/{}) -{}{} Username: {} Taken{}'.format(Fore.WHITE, self.count, self.line_count, Fore.RESET, Fore.RED, username, Fore.RESET))
```

The output of my Program is here :

```
[+]Trying (1/1) - 
[+]Trying (2/2) -
[+]Trying (3/3) -
[+]Trying (4/4) -
[+]Trying (5/5) -
[+]Trying (6/6) -
[+]Trying (7/7) -
[+]Trying (8/8) - 
[+]Trying (9/9) -
[+]Trying (10/10) - 
....

but i want output :
    [+]Trying (1/20) - 
    [+]Trying (2/20) -
    [+]Trying (3/20) -
    [+]Trying (4/20) -
    [+]Trying (5/20) -
    [+]Trying (6/20) -
```

How can i fix it in   `with open(self.usersfile, 'rt') as f:`

Comment: You are missing most of your `class` definition,  `self.usersfile` is unspecified, the `replace` in `line.strip().replace('\n', '')` is wasted because `strip()` already gets rid of `\n` at the ends - there can not be a `\n` inside `line`, because then it would be a seperate line... beside that - your indentation needs serious fixes to make this valid code. Please fix the issues so we have a [minimal verifyable complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to work with and to help you with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are increasing your total line count incrementally with each processed line.

Read in the full file into a list, then process the list. While processing the list, increase a counter thats "the current lines nr" and pass it to the output function as well. The `len()` of your list is the total line count you can set to `self.line_count`:

```
def start(self):
    with open(self.usersfile, 'rt') as f:
         allLines = f.readlines()
    self.line_count = len(allLines)     
    currLine = 0
    for line in allLines:
         currLine += 1
         # do what you need to do, do not increment self.line_count
         self.check_account(username, currLine) # extend your printmethod to take the 
                                                # currLine nrand print that instead 
                                                # of self.count 
# simplified
def check_account(self,username,currLine):
    print ("{} {}/{}".format(username,currLine,self.line_count) )
```

Comment: i got alueError: I/O operation on closed file. error .

Comment: @Mehran you already read in _all data_ from the file. It is inside `allLines` - do not operate on the file anymore, only operate on and use the `allLines` list.

Comment: for line in allLines():
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Comment: @Mehran `for line in allLines()` is _not in this sample code_. You've added `()` yourself, making it a function call